# How to add a JSON array to an infinite amount of option menus?

Tags: javascript, json

For a WebInterface I need to add a JSON array to an infinite amount of option menus with JavaScript. I'm still new to programming with JavaScript and I thought you could help me.

I found a solution for adding a JSON array to an optionmenu which worked so I tried to add some code to make it work with an infinite amount of option menus.

I have two select tags:

```
<select id="selection1" class="selectionMenu"> </select>
<select id="selection2" class="selectionMenu"> </select>
```

the following code is the script I worked out to add option tags into both of the select menus which doesn't work for me.

```
<script>

 var arr = [
  'selection1',
  'selection2'
 ]

 var arrLen = arr.length - 1;

 for (j = 0; j < arrLen; j++) {

  var arrElm = arr[j];

  var select = doucment.getElementById(arrElm);

  var text = '{"nrrps":[' +
   '{"dbC":"PI1","PIIP":"192.168.2.17" },' +
   '{"dbC":"PI2","PIIP":"192.168.2.18" },' + 
   '{"dbC":"PI3","PIIP":"192.168.2.19" }]}';

  for (i=0; i < text.length; i++;) {

   var opt = document.createElement('option');

   var counter2 = i + 1;

   obj = JSON.parse(text);

   var insertText = obj.nrrps[i].dbC + " " + obj.nrrps[i].PIIP + " ";

   var optVal = obj.nrrps[i].dbC;

   opt.value = optVal;

   opt.innerHTML = insertText;

   opt.setAttribute("class", "sOption");

   select.appendChild(opt);

  }

 }

</script>
```

When I run the code, the JSON array is inserted into the first select tag but not the second one. I don't know why. In addition is there a possibility to get the value of every select tag after choosing the options?

I hope you can help me with this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** First as @kamesh mentioned you already `applied -1` in length so change the operator like below  `j <= arrLen;`

```
for (j = 0; j <= arrLen; j++) { ... }
```

**2nd :**  In second `for loop` your checking `length` for text so it will give the text length `122 something` .it's wrong so you need to apply `JSON.parse()` then find length of option like below

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);

for (i=0; i < obj.nrrps.length; i++) {...}
```

```js
var arr = [
   'selection1',
   'selection2'
  ]

 var arrLen = arr.length - 1;

 for (j = 0; j <= arrLen; j++) {

  var arrElm = arr[j];

  var select = document.getElementById(arrElm);

  var text = '{"nrrps":[' +
      '{"dbC":"PI1","PIIP":"192.168.2.17" },' +
      '{"dbC":"PI2","PIIP":"192.168.2.18" },' + 
      '{"dbC":"PI3","PIIP":"192.168.2.19" }]}';
  
  //console.log(text.length);
  
  var obj = JSON.parse(text);
  
  for (i=0; i < obj.nrrps.length; i++) {

   var opt = document.createElement('option');

   var counter2 = i + 1;

   var insertText = obj.nrrps[i].dbC + " " + obj.nrrps[i].PIIP + " ";

   var optVal = obj.nrrps[i].dbC;

   opt.value = optVal;

   opt.innerHTML = insertText;

   opt.setAttribute("class", "sOption");

   select.appendChild(opt);

  }

 }
```

```html
<select id="selection1" class="selectionMenu"> </select>
<select id="selection2" class="selectionMenu"> </select>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are already subtracting one from your array length. So run your for loop till <= array.length.

```
....
....
for (j = 0; j <= arrLen; j++) {

  var arrElm = arr[j];
....
....
```